# Regex how to match the group that was matched

Tags: javascript, regex

Like for example here:

```
/(\.\s)|(\!\s)|(\?\s)|(\:\s)/
```

So for example if the ? is matched I want it to be replaced with itself. Obviously matching with `"$1"` wouldn't work too well here.

EDIT: It seems it needs more explanation. So if I have this string:

```
OK good. And this sentence? And maybe even this one!
```

Then I can match the endings. So its matching the punctuation.

Comment: This is very broad/it's unclear what you're asking. Include the actual question in your question (not just in the title). Can you also provide us with sample input and expected output. I fear your question will be closed otherwise. On another note, you can change `(\.\s)|(\!\s)|(\?\s)|(\:\s)` to `([.!?:]\s)`

Comment: Also, as you question is marked with `php` tag, please provide the complete PHP code.

Comment: You can evaluate captures inside `preg_replace_callback` callback function and replace accordingly.

Comment: You could use all capture groups `$1$2$3$4` the ones that didn't match won't be present... or please provide a clearer picture of what you are doing.

Comment: 1. Do you use composer? 2. Can you provide some code you are using? 3. For what ending do you use this, is it for stripping characters or BB codes, anything else?

Comment: Oh really? If you select all four matching groups it will only match one of them? I didn't realise that.

Comment: The ones not used will contain nothing. For punctuation though you can just do `[.!?]`.

Comment: @Hasen if you use one capture group as I put in my comment, you only have to use `$1`. What are you trying to do with this regex? There may be a better approach if you can properly explain the program's intent

Comment: So, you have `OK good. And this sentence? And maybe even this one!`, what is the expected output and why?

Comment: +chris85 "For punctuation though you can just do [.!?]" That doesn't work because you're not getting the space \s in the capture group.

Comment: +chris85 Your answer $1$2$3$4 works great. It answers the simple question - how to replace the group that was matched. If you want to add it as your answer I can accept it.

Comment: @chris85 ping...

Comment: @Hasen You need to use the `@` for notifications to be sent. You could add the whitespace after the character class and it should perform the same `[!?.]\s` then use `$0`. If that works better please comment and I can add it to the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, moved it to an answer.

Comment: @chris85 So you mean `([!?.]\s)`  ?

Comment: You don't need the capture group `$0` will be the full match. https://regex101.com/r/Mlg8Pn/1/

Comment: @chris85 It works with the capture group and $1, but not sure why but $0 doesn't work at all. It just replaces it with a $0 but with $1 it works fine...not sure why but anyway at least it works like that. I can see you have it working in regex101 though and my code is identical so not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Can you post an example of your code on https://3v4l.org/?

Comment: @chris85 Actually I used it in javascript. I copied the code I used directly into regex101 and it works there but not in plain javascript so I don't know what it is. Maybe $0 doesn't work with js? Anyway it works fine with $1 its just a matter of adding brackets in so its no big problem. I wrote a little block of code with a couple of sentences in a variable, purely to check just this match and it still didn't work so I'm guessing it just doesn't work with js or something.

Comment: Oh, so we're not in PHP. Try https://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use every capture group in the replacement and only the matched group will have a value. So for the regex you've provided use:

```
$1$2$3$4
```

If the third capture group is matched `$3` will be populated and all others empty.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to

```
/([.!?:])\s/
```

Now you can match group 1 to get the punctuations.

Comment: That way you lose the space in the capture group..Look at my code and you'll see that yours doesn't give the same results. In mine the space \s is within each capture group. I think only $1$2$3$4 works.